# Decay of amplitude integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, quantum-field-theory

Consider the function

$$
f(\vec{x}) = 
\int_{\Bbb R^3} {\frac{ e^{-i\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{k}}}{\sqrt{\vec{k}^2 + m^2}}} d^3 k
$$

from Zee's *Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell*. He argues like this: “the square root cut starting at $±im$ tells us that the characteristic value of $|\vec{k}|$ in the integral is of order $m$, leading to an exponential decay $\sim e^{−m|\vec{x}|}$”. I cannot understand what he means. It would be nice if someone can expand or suggest a reference for me. Thanks.

Comment: What he likely means is that - to take a 1D analog - the integral may be expressed by Cauchy's Theorem as  $$\int_m^{\infty} dk \, \frac{e^{-k x}}{\sqrt{k^2-m^2}} $$ which may be shown to be dominated by the contribution near $k=m$.

Comment: I have been thinking about the residue stuff too, but how does it lead to the bound $e^{-m|\vec{x}|}$. And what is the precise definition of "be dominated" ?

Comment: Note that I am keeping this to a comment because I do not wish to get into precise definitions at this point.  I am using the language of Steepest Descents.  Think about approximating the integral with a sum (avoiding the "pole"), what term or terms make the biggest contribution to the sum?  That's what I mean by "dominating."

Comment: Thanks, that Steepest Descent does make sense; although I still cannot see how to bound the integral by $e^{-m|\vec{x}|}$.

Answer (score 1):

Letting 
\begin{align*}
\vec{x}&=(0,0,x), \\
\vec{k}&=k(\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi),
\end{align*}
and integrating over $\theta$ and $\phi$ we find 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R^3} 
{\frac{ e^{-i\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{k}}}{\sqrt{\vec{k}^2 + m^2}}}\,
d^3 k
&= 
\frac{4\pi}{x}
\int_0^\infty \frac{k\sin k x}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\,dk 
= \frac{2\pi}{x}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{k\sin k x}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\,dk \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{x} \textrm{Im}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{k e^{i k x}}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\,dk. 
\end{align*}
An integral of exactly this form is worked out in detail  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131904/26872).