# Problems 2.3 in Peskin's book

Tags: integration, contour-integration, quantum-field-theory

It's about how to evaluate the integral below,
$$
D(x-y)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}e^{-i\vec p\cdot (\vec x-\vec y)}
$$
it describes the amplitude for a scalar particle in free Klein-Gordon field propagating from y to x (y and x have a space-like interval) .
The book said that the result can be written explicitly in terms of Bessel function but I have not idea at all.

Comment: Go to spherical coordinate, do the integration over the angles first. You will need to use the integral representation of the Bessel functions, which can be found in wikipedia, for example.

Comment: also, choose youre spherical coordinates such that $\vec{p}(\vec{x}-\vec{y}) = p \lvert \vec{x}-\vec{y}\rvert \cos\theta$ ($\theta$ being the azimuth of your coordinate system)

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: See Weinberg I page 202.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131812/26872)